# Why does this final.exe file execute in an infinite loop instead of the specified number as below?

Tags: c, linux, argv, argc

- final.exe file.
- this executes infinitely or up to 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   int i; 
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("ERROR: You need at least one argument.\n");
        return 1;
    } 
   else 
   {
        int i, j;
          
           for(i=1;i<=(int)*argv[1];i++)
            {
                printf("\n");
                (void)system("test1.exe");
            }
    } 
}
```

test.c file contains :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

- Expected - For ex. : ./final 2 : The output should be Hello World Hello World , i.e, prints only 2 times and not infinitely.

Comment: `argv` contains an array of strings.  `*argv[1]` contains the first character in the string.  By casting that to an int, you are getting the integer representation of that character.  With ASCII encoding ( https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html ), for example, the char `'2'` would be the number 50.  You should instead be making use of a library function like `strtol` to convert a string into an integer.

Comment: how are you executing this/what are your arguments? `final.exe file.`? In that case you'd be isolating the char `'f'` in file, which for ASCII is 102, so neither infinite or 50 times makes sense to me.

Comment: @yano OP did give an example running with `./final 2`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons gotcha, I see it now, missed it originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(int)*argv[1]` is using the character code of the first character as the number of iteration. Character codes are usually differ from the number that the character represents.

To convert a string to corresponding number, you can use [`atoi()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) (if you don't care about invalid input).

```
        int i, j;
        int num = atoi(argv[1]);
          
           for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
            {
                printf("\n");
                (void)system("test1.exe");
            }
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just as soon never teach people that `atoi()` exists and instead teach them to just use `strtol()` family to start good habits early.

Answer (score 1):

> `for(i=1;i<=(int)*argv[1];i++)`

The expression `(int)*argv[1]` uses the first character of the first command line argument (not counting the program name) as a number. That is, assuming an ASCII-like or Unicode-like encoding, the character `0` is treated as value 48, `1` as 49, ..., and `9` as 57.  The `(int)` doesn't really make a difference.

If you really want to use just that first character, you could do something like

```
if (isdigit(*argv[1])) {
    int count = *argv[1] - '0'; // works with any encoding
```

Or to allow multi-digit counts, you could do something like

```
char *parse_end;
int count = strtol(argv[1], &parse_end, 10);
if (parse_end != argv[1] && *parse_end == '\0' && count >= 0) {
```

Comment: `std::isdigit` is invalid as C. You should use `isdigit` without `std::`.